# How can I intergrate socketio with nuxt

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, nuxt.js

I am using this nuxt/express template
https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template/tree/master/template

I am trying to intergrate socketio, but I can't really seem to figure it out. As if you go to the api/index you can see it's exporting the app, and I am not sure if I should host it on another port, but it won't be ideal. So kinda stuck.